# Calculating $\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}f(x,y)$ where $f(x,y)= \begin{cases} \frac{e^x -e^y}{\log(x)-\log(y) } & \ x \neq y\\ xe^x & x=y \end{cases}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, continuity

Hey I have to study the existence of the limit of this function at $(0,0)$:

$f:(0,+\infty)\times(0,+\infty)\to\Bbb R $
$$f(x,y)=
\begin{cases}
\frac{e^x -e^y}{\log(x)-\log(y)  } & \ x \neq y\\ 
xe^x & x=y
\end{cases}$$

I tried to find curves where the limits were different, but I couldn't find any: all that I tried tend to zero. So  I tried to
delimit the function, but I couldn't do it either.

I think the limit does not exist but I don't know how to prove it.

Comment: Can you show that $f(x,y) \le \max (xe^x, ye^y)$ for all $(x,y)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have to precise that it is more a question of continuity in $(0,0)$

We have to show in the will of showing f is continuous that the limit goes to $ f(0,0)=0 $

Use **Mean Value Theorem** :

Let $x\neq y$,

$$ h:x\to e^x$$
$$g:x\to \ln(x)$$

$$ \exists c_1\in]x,y[ \ , h'(c_1) =\dfrac{\ln(x)-\ln(y)}{x-y} $$
$$ \exists c_2\in]x,y[ \ , g'(c_2) =\dfrac{e^x-e^y}{x-y} $$

So you have , because of $c_1,c_2\to 0$ when $(x,y) \to 0. $ (Use $ |c_{1,2}-x|<|x-y|$)

$$ f(x,y)=\frac{g'(c_2)}{h'(c_1)}=\frac{e^x-e^y}{\ln(x)-\ln(y)}=\dfrac{c_2}{e^{c_1}}_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\to0$$

Then:
$$
\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} f(x,y) = \lim_{(c_1,_2)\to(0,0)} \frac{c_2}{e^{c_1}} = 0
$$
Thus continuity.

Comment: Obvioulsy it isnt the same $c$ thanks for editing.